# Create conditional unique constraints on multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, unique

I need to create a conditional unique constraint on multiple columns using Oracle but I am failing to do so.

Below is what I have right now but it's not working:

Basically, my conditional unique constraint needs to handle a combination of columns under one condition which a = 1.

`alter table <table_name> add constraint <constraint_name> unique (<column_1>, <column_2>, a = 1);`

I get this error when I run this alter statement:

`ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`

Comment: As far as I can tell, that won't work as you planned. Perhaps enforcing it with a database trigger. Though, you didn't say what if `a <> 1`. Some sample data which shows valid and invalid rows might help someone to help you.

Comment: As littlefoot said. If `a` is also a field you cant do that in a constraint.

Comment: `a` is a column in the same table. If that cannot be done, then how else can I go about this? perhaps `unique index` with `case statements`?

Comment: Your requirement is not clear, I don;t know what do you want to achieve, but you can replace `a = 1` with `case when a = 1 then 1 else 0 end` or `case when a = 1 then 1  end`. The first version allows for only one record a=1 and only one record a<>1, the second version is less restrictive - allows for only one record a=1 and multiple records a<>1.

Comment: @krokodilko please see answer below and let me know what do you think?

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=how-to-enforce-conditional-unique-on-multiple-columns

Comment: Is it your requirement that the combination of column_1 and column_2 be unique if `a` equals 1?

Comment: @BobJarvis yes sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is sufficient:

```
create unique index <index_name> on <table_name> (case when a = 1 then <column_1> end, 
                                                  case when a = 1 then <column_2> end);
```